# Pass ViewModel to JSONresult in controller

Tags: model-view-controller, model, jsonresult

My application was working but I was asked to change how message are displayed by using the JSONResponseFactory.  But when I try that my ViewModel is empty going back to the JSonResult (which used to be ActionResult).  I've been told I may have to serialize the form fields.  Here are some present code excerpts:

cshtml:

```
    function SubmitForm() {


    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.post('@Url.Action("StoreLevelPlanning", "StoreLevelPlanning")', { actionType: "Submit"})

    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.Success == true) {
            CreateInformationMessage(data.Message, 'window.location.href = "@Url.Action("storemanagement", "AccountListing")";');
        }
        else {
            CreateErrorMessage(data.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult StoreLevelPlanning_Post(string actionType)  // actionType is Save or Submit
    {
        // message to return to the view on success
        string successMessage = "";
        var model = new VM_StoreLevelPlanning();
        TryUpdateModel(model);
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.buttonPressed = actionType;
                repo.UpdateCLPCategoryAndRemark(model);

                //Render different message depending on ActionType
                if (actionType == "Save")
                {
                    successMessage = "Your plan was saved.  You  will now be directed to the Listing Screen";
                }
                else if (actionType == "Submit")
                {
                    successMessage = "Your plan has been submitted. You will now be directed to the  Listing Screen.";
                }
                else
                {
                    //return RedirectToAction("storemanagement", "AccountListing");
                    // need to revisit to figure out if this can be removed
                    throw new Exception("Else case happened");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (actionType == "Save")
                {
                    // TODO : change this to throw an error so that the ErrorLog class is utilized
                    throw new Exception("Your plan was not saved. Please retry.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO : change this to throw an error so that the ErrorLog class is utilized
                    throw new Exception("Your plan was not submitted. Please retry.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(JsonResponseFactory.ErrorResponse(e.Message));
        }
        return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse(successMessage));
    }
```

I'm open to any suggestions since I'm new to MVC.  The idea is to put out a successful save message and redirect the user to the Listing page.  But he way I changed the code now the view model is empty.  It does not use a form collection.  The data is in a list in the view model.

Thank you in advance...